# How to make random selector only pick shown items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yeah not very familiar with JQuery and I'm trying to make a random lunch picker for our web team.

http://jsfiddle.net/vy8RL/1/

I want to hide certain items. For example when you hit the "Quick Eats" button it only displays 4 options and when you hit "EAT ME" it still selects the LI's that are hidden. Is there any way to allow it only to select options that are visible?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#button").click(function(){
    random();
  });
      $("#unhealthy-food").click(function(){
      $(".unhealthy").hide();
    });
      $("#all").click(function(){
      $("li").show();
    });
       $("#fast-food").click(function(){
      $(".food").hide();
      $(".fast").show();
    });

});


function random() {
        $("li.selected").removeClass("selected");
        var menuItems = $("ul#list li");
        var numItems = menuItems.length;
        if(window.sessionStorage && window.sessionStorage.getItem("selected")) {
            previous = Number(window.sessionStorage.getItem("selected"));
        } else {
            previous = -1;             
        }
        var selected = Math.floor(Math.random()*numItems);
        while(selected === previous && numItems > 1) {
            selected = Math.floor(Math.random()*numItems);
        }
        if(window.sessionStorage)  window.sessionStorage.setItem("selected", selected);
        $("ul#list li:nth-child("+(selected+1)+")").addClass("selected");  
}
```

Comment: _"Is there any way to allow it only to select options that are visible?"_, Yes, `$yourjQueryOptionCollection.filter(':visible')`.

Comment: I only wrote the top part and have very limited jquery knowledge, how would I add that in?

Comment: FYI, clicking quick food then healthy food will not bring back all healthy food. I've fixed that in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:visible` selector:

```
function random() {
    $("li.selected").removeClass("selected");
    var menuItems = $("#list li").filter(':visible');
    var numItems = menuItems.length;
    // ...
    menuItems.eq(selected).addClass("selected");  
}
```

Please note that I have replaced the `$("ul#list li:nth-child("+(selected+1)+")")` with the cached collection + `eq()` method.

http://jsfiddle.net/3n9ex/

Answer (score 0):

here you go. I just added tracking of menu preference. Also added `$(".food").show();` in line 9 to correct a bug.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var user_choice = ".food";
    $("#button").click(function(){
        random(user_choice);
    });
    $("#unhealthy-food").click(function(){
        user_choice = "li:not(.unhealthy)";
        $(".food").show();
        $(".unhealthy").hide();
    });
    $("#all").click(function(){
        $("li").show();
        user_choice = ".food";
    });
    $("#fast-food").click(function(){
        $(".food").hide();
        $(".fast").show();
        user_choice = ".fast";
    });

});


function random(user_choice) {
    $("li.selected").removeClass("selected");
    var menuItems = $(user_choice);
    console.log(menuItems);
    var numItems = menuItems.length;
    if(window.sessionStorage && window.sessionStorage.getItem("selected")) {
        previous = Number(window.sessionStorage.getItem("selected"));
    } else {
        previous = -1;             
    }
    var selected = Math.floor(Math.random()*numItems);
    while(selected === previous && numItems > 1) {
        selected = Math.floor(Math.random()*numItems);
    }
    if(window.sessionStorage)  window.sessionStorage.setItem("selected", selected);
    $(menuItems[selected]).addClass("selected");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vy8RL/19/